# Get an information about defined attributes without __dict__ or dir()

Tags: python, class

So, let's say I want to write my own class, rewriting `__getattribute__` function. Every time, when someone calls attribute, which was not defined, I want it to generate a random int.

```
X = GetAttribute()
print(X.predefined_attribute) # "First attribute"
X.attr2 = "Hi"
print(X.attr2) # "Hi"
print(X.attr3) # random int
```

Obviously, I can't write something like this, as it would cause a recursion.

```
class GetAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.predefined_attribute = "First attribute"

    def __getattribute__(self, attr): 
        if attr not in self.__dict__: # the bad line
            return randint(0, 9999)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

How, without using `__dict__`, can I get an information about defined attributes?

Comment: Your recursion is caused by an assumption that all attributes must live in `__dict__`. You should check the *class* first however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly urge you to reconsider overriding `__getattribute__` and use the [`object.__getattr__()` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) instead. That method is called automatically for any *missing attribute*, and won't interfere with `dir()` or `__dict__` introspection:

```
class GetAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.predefined_attribute = "First attribute"

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # self.__dict__ can be used here but is not needed for your
        # sample usecase.
        return randint(0, 9999)
```

Your own implementation is flawed because you failed to check the *class* for your attribute. `__dict__` is a descriptor on the class, and trying to access `self.__dict__` is handled by `object.__getattribute__` too, triggering your infinite recursion. You can avoid the issue entirely by using  `object.__getattribute__` **first**. You could just catch the `AttributeError` exception this could throw:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr): 
    try:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        return randint(0, 9999)
```

The more painful path would be to re-implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to retrieve your `__dict__` attribute before testing:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr): 
    cls = type(self)
    # retrieve the __dict__ descriptor, and bind it to the instance
    __dict__ = cls.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(self)
    # test against the instance dictionary and all classes in the MRO
    if attr not in __dict__ and not any(attr in c.__dict__ for c in cls.__mro__):
        return randint(0, 9999)
    return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

or you could access `self.__dict__` via `object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')`. You do have to test the class MRO too, because those provide attributes for your instances too; you wouldn't want `X.__class__` to return a random integer rather than `GetAttribute` itself.

However, this use-case is already covered by implementing `__getattr__` instead, a much cleaner and simpler option.

Last but not least, instead of using `object.__getattribute__(self, ...)`, you should use `super().__getattribute__(...)` to ensure you are not skipping any other `__getattribute__` hooks in your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bypass your own `__getattribute__`, for example to get at the "real" `self.__dict__`, you can explicitly call the superclass `__getattribute__`:

```
if attr not in super().__getattribute__('__dict__'):
```

However, for your case, it'd probably be easier to just implement `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`. `__getattr__` is only called for attribute lookups that `__getattribute__` raises an `AttributeError` on:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return randint(0, 9999)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Whoops. Fixed.

Comment: And testing for `attr in instance.__dict__`, however way is used to retrieve that object, is not enough; there are other attributes available on the instance that `__getattribute__` would find but are missed this way. Like `instance.__class__`.